# Чтение/запись в /proc

Tags: linux, c

Проблема заключется в том, что при чтении из файла вылетает сообщение «killed».
Есть мысль, что что-то не так с чтением. Но что? А кто его знает...
Вот код:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/seq_file.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

#define TASKLIST "tasklist"
#define TASKS    "tasks"

int open_proc(struct inode *inode, struct  file *file);  
int open_proc_message(void); 
ssize_t read_proc (struct seq_file *m, void *v); 
int create_task_entry(void); 
ssize_t write_proc(struct file *filp, const char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *offp);
static struct proc_dir_entry *proc_entry;
static struct proc_dir_entry *dir_entry;
static char *msg = "hello";

struct file_operations file_fops = {
 .owner   = THIS_MODULE,
 .open    = open_proc,
 .read    = read_proc,
 .write   = write_proc,
 .release = single_release,
};

int create_task_entry(void) {
    int ret = 0; 
    if(!(dir_entry = proc_mkdir(TASKLIST, NULL))){
        printk(KERN_INFO "Can't create the directory %s. Bye\n", TASKLIST);
        ret = -ENOMEM;
    }

    //create file 
    if (!(proc_entry  = proc_create(TASKS, 0664, dir_entry, &file_fops))) {
       remove_proc_entry(TASKLIST, NULL);
       ret = -ENOMEM;
    }

    return ret;
}

int open_proc(struct inode *inode, struct file *file) {
    return single_open(file, read_proc, NULL);
}

ssize_t read_proc (struct seq_file *m, void *v) {
    if (msg)
        seq_printf(m,"%s\n", msg);
    return 0;
}

int open_proc_message(void) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "File was opened!\n\n");
    return 0;
}

int init_module(void) {
    return create_task_entry();
}

void cleanup_module(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning Up.\n");
    remove_proc_entry(TASKLIST, NULL);
    remove_proc_entry(TASKS,NULL);
}

ssize_t write_proc(struct file *filp, const char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *offp){
    msg = (char*)kmalloc(255 * sizeof(char), GFP_KERNEL);
    copy_from_user(msg, buf, count);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: seq_* новый для меня интерфейс, раньше такого не было и read работал на подобии write, только copy_to_user. Вот смотрю исходники ядра. И вижу, что в случае использования seq_* в file_opertions передается всегда .read=seq_read, а не собственный обработчик и функция открытия файла посложнее чем у вас. Если вы вешаете свой обработчик на read, то у него параметры совсем другие, похожие на те, что у вашего write. И никаких seq_file там и в помине нет. seq_file передается обработчику который видимо вызывает seq_read, за счет регистрации при seq_open с использованием структуры seq_operations

Comment: Ну и у вас утечка памяти при write, вы память выделяете и нигде ее не освобождаете

Answer (score 1):

Переделал под запись в /proc.  Чтение данного файла с user space корректно.
Вот код:

```
    #include <linux/kernel.h>
    #include <linux/sched.h>
    #include <linux/module.h>
    #include <linux/string.h>
    #include <linux/syscalls.h>
    #include <linux/vmalloc.h>
    #include <linux/proc_fs.h>
    #include <asm/uaccess.h>
    #include <linux/cdev.h>
    int create_proc_entry(void);
    static int tasks_proc_show(struct  seq_file *m, void *v);
    static int tasks_proc_open(struct inode *inode, struct  file *file);
    static const struct file_operations file_fops = {
     .open = tasks_proc_open,
     .read = seq_read,
     .write = seq_write,
     .llseek = seq_lseek,
     .release = single_release,
    };

    static int tasks_proc_show(struct  seq_file *m, void *v){
      struct task_struct *task = &init_task;
      while((task = next_task(task))!= &init_task)
      seq_printf(m,"%s %d\n",task->comm, task->pid);
      return 0;
    }
   static int tasks_proc_open(struct inode *inode, struct  file *file){
      single_open(file, tasks_proc_show, NULL);
    }
  int proc_init(void) {
     proc_create("ltask",0,NULL,&file_fops);
     return 0;
  }
  void proc_cleanup(void) {
     remove_proc_entry("ltask",NULL);
  }
  MODULE_LICENSE("GPL"); 
  module_init(proc_init);
  module_exit(proc_cleanup);
```